# Which values of 'x' are equal to the functional represention of the power series?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I know the summation notation for the power series is equivalent to the following function:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

However, what does it mean if I'm asked which values of *x* are equal to the function representation above? Is this another way of asking for the interval of convergence?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The series converges when $|x|<1$

Comment: One side is defined for $|x|<1$ and one side is defined for $x \neq 1$. What is the overlap?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, copper.hat. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by the "overlap", but it was not specified in the problem I've referenced.

Comment: @user1505087:  copper.hat defined two subsets of the real line.  The overlap is their intersection.  As the first is a subset of the second, the overlap matches the first, $|x| \lt 1$